# I am getting the following error while connecting to QBO online in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

While making connection using OAuth v1.0 for QBO intuit in coldfusion.
All the things are working fine on localhost but went wrong when I upload my code to live site.

Things I have tried:

Clear cache/cookie
Tested on multiple browsers
Updated java to latest version

I am getting error on following line => DataService.add(customer)

java.lang.NullPointerException at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.HTTPClientConnectionInterceptor.getRetryHandler(HTTPClientConnectionInterceptor.java:215) at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.HTTPClientConnectionInterceptor.execute(HTTPClientConnectionInterceptor.java:85) at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeRequestInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:80) at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:66) at com.intuit.ipp.services.DataService.add(DataService.java:110) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor138.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at coldfusion.runtime.StructBean.invoke(StructBean.java:508) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:3168) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:3068) at cforderSearch2ecfc1073923015$funcUPDATE_VENDOR_DIRECT_INVOICE._factor8(C:\home\fourwaywarehouse.com\wwwroot\test\cfc\orderSearch\orderSearch.cfc:834) at cforderSearch2ecfc1073923015$funcUPDATE_VENDOR_DIRECT_INVOICE._factor11(C:\home\fourwaywarehouse.com\wwwroot\test\cfc\orderSearch\orderSearch.cfc:779) at cforderSearch2ecfc1073923015$funcUPDATE_VENDOR_DIRECT_INVOICE._factor12(C:\home\fourwaywarehouse.com\wwwroot\test\cfc\orderSearch\orderSearch.cfc:756) at cforderSearch2ecfc1073923015$funcUPDATE_VENDOR_DIRECT_INVOICE.runFunction(C:\home\fourwaywarehouse.com\wwwroot\test\cfc\orderSearch\orderSearch.cfc:744) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:492) at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:425) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:388) at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:339) at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:538) at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:655) at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:464) at coldfusion.filter.ComponentFilter.invoke(ComponentFilter.java:251) at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:498) at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:43) at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:153) at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:60) at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.invoke(CFCServlet.java:156) at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.doPost(CFCServlet.java:348) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:286) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:283) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:549) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:318) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:173) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:286) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:286) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:283) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:549) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:318) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:258) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:286) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:283) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:549) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:318) at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:258) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:536) at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:898) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Post code, not images.